# Peform tasks based upon matching files last modified stamp being greater than x minutes

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, last-modified

The following batch program, when I execute it, the files are moved correctly, and the .dat files are correctly deleted.

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set sourceFolder=C:\test_S
set destinationFolder=C:\test_D

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set datetime=%%a

set currentDate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
set currentTime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

for %%F in (%sourceFolder%\*.zip) do (
    set fileModifiedDate=

    for %%G in (%%F) do set fileModifiedDate=%%~tG

    set fileDate=!fileModifiedDate:~6,4!!fileModifiedDate:~3,2!!fileModifiedDate:~0,2!
    set fileTime=!fileModifiedDate:~11,2!!fileModifiedDate:~14,2!

    set /a elapsedMinutes=currentDate*1440+currentTime/100-fileDate*1440-fileTime/100

    if !elapsedMinutes! geq 2 (
        set baseFileName=%%~nF
        set tmpFileName=!baseFileName!.tmp
        set zipFileName=!tmpFileName!.zip

        ren %%F !tmpFileName!
        move %sourceFolder%\!tmpFileName! %destinationFolder%
        ren %destinationFolder%\!tmpFileName! !zipFileName!
    
        set datFilePath=%sourceFolder%\!baseFileName!.dat
        if exist !datFilePath! (
            del !datFilePath!
        )
    )
)

endlocal
```

However, I want the files to be moved only if it has a last modified time of greater than 2 minutes ago.

To clarify, if a zip file's last modified date is greater that two minutes, move it, and delete the adjacent dat file with the same basename.

Could someone help me with that?

I would prefer it to be in batch because a part of my script is already in that language.

Comment: okay i'm sorry about that, i actually have a program that i'll add to the question above, it correctly does what i want wich is transfer some files from one directory to another, but i want it to do it only if the file was modified at least 2 minutes ago, wich it doesnt do for now

Comment: What's the problem with the code?  How does the output differ from your expectations? (and what **is** the output and what **is** your expectation?)

Comment: when i execute the program, the files are moved correctly, the .dat files correctly deleted, but i want the files to be moved only if it was last edited at least 2 mitunes ago. For now, the program only calculate if the last edit date was before the actual date, wich is always the case i guess ?
I would know if i can do so that it moves only if the last edit date = actual date - 2 or more minutes

Comment: check the assembly of `currentdate` You're comparing DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY, (according to your local date format) with YYYYMMDD - which will do nonsense.

Comment: thanks, didn't see that ! i changed line 16 so all dates formats are DDMMYYYY, but it still won't do what i want

Comment: to compare dates, use ISO format `YYYYMMDD`. `if` can only compare strings, not dates.

Comment: okay i changed it again, but i think that my !elapsedMinutes! has a problem somewheere, could you help me with that ?

Comment: What about simpifying it by getting assistance from PowerShell instead of WMIC: **1.** ```@Set "sourceFolder=C:\test_S"```, **2.** ```@Set "destinationFolder=C:\test_D"```, **3.** ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path '%sourceFolder%' -Filter '*.zip' -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -GT (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2)} | Move-Item -Destination '%destinationFolder%'"```.

Comment: thank you, im not sure in wich part of my program should i put this in ?

Comment: Replace everything you posted as code with those three lines.

Comment: okay fine, i did it, but when i execute it, it only moves the last edited zip file, but i want to move all the ones that are older than 2 minutes at the same time. i also want to delete the dat files (all zip file has a dat file with the same name, i wantto delete the dat file named like the zip file once it's moved).

Comment: I know that you have not searched StackOverFlow for a solution to your issue because it has been answered plenty of times before.